# Convert from absolute path to IFile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working at an eclipse plugin where the projects which exist in the `Project Explorer` view have a different workspace name than the actual path of the project. So considering a project located at `D:\test` when I try to get the project location, it points to `D:\test_plugin_specific_suffix`.

Is there a way to get an IFile from an absolute path (which points to the local path, `D:\test\testfile.txt`)?

I want to create a hyperlink to a specific file for which I have the absolute path. When I click on console on the hyperlink it should open in the editor the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `IWorkspaceRoot.findFilesForLocationURI` to find the `IFile` corresponding to a absolute path (there might be more than one if you are 
using links):

```java
File file = new File(....absolue path);
URI location = file.toURI();
IFile[] files = ResourcesPlugin
   .getWorkspace()
   .getRoot()
   .findFilesForLocationURI( location );
```

Comment: That puts me in a hard situation since there are projects with lots of duplicate files which may or may not be filtered

Comment: Also the plugin uses a flat folder where it copies all the used files, but I have to create a hyperlink to the original file location, not the flat folder location.

Comment: Actually, I will give it a try because it seems like this will achieve what I'm trying to get. I don't think I will run into multiple links situation, the files have a 1 to 1 corespondence in the workspace. Thanks Greg, I will come back to accept your solution after I validate it.