# How to pass absolute file-path to IFile

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtend

I hope you all are doing good. I'm stuck in some part of the code while passing absolute file-path to IFile. Please guide me to resolve these issues. I'm using Xtend in eclipse. But you can provide me the answer in java also.

```
class A{
  def x(){

 - 

val file = new File("D:\\xyz.xml")
   val ifile = file as IFile // Getting error here
   new B().y(ifile) 
  }
}
class B{
 def y(IFile file){

  //do something

 }
}
```

I'm getting error while type-casting **java.io.File cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile**  thank you in advance.

I tried with this solution

[Convert from absolute path to IFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139578/convert-from-absolute-path-to-ifile)

But I'm not abale to achieve my solution. Give me some other solution for passing absolute path to IFile.

Also I tried in other ways :

```
class A{
 def x(){
  val file = new File("D:\\xyz.xml")
  val workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
  val location= Path.fromOSString(file.getAbsolutePath());
  val ifile= workspace.root.getFileForLocation(location)
  new B().y(ifile)
 }
}
class B{
 def y(IFile file){
  //do somthing
 }
}
```

Then it is showing some error like Workspace is closed   **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:412)**

Comment: The code you implemented for that solution isn't here, though. Can you show that?

Comment: I have edited my Query.

Comment: 'Workspace is closed' usually means you are trying to use this code in a plain Java program - the workspace only works in an Eclipse plug-in installed in Eclipse or a RCP (or a headless RCP). Also IFile will only work for a file in the workspace - it can't be just any file.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your response. I'll try it.